# Laravel - Property does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel

On my Users model I have a query that gives me "Property [manager_id] does not exist on this collection instance" error. I suppose this is because the collection of expiringUsers does not have a single property manager_id, but I'm not sure how to loop through expiringUsers in the query.

What I'm trying to return is a collection of managers where their ID matches the expiring manager_id.

```
public function scopeManagers()
    {   

        $expiringUsers = $this->ExpiringContractors(); // This returns a collection of users
        return $mangers = $this->where(function($query) use ($expiringUsers){
                    $query->where('id', $expiringUsers->manager_id);
                })->get();



    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already said it yourself... If `$expiringUsers` is a `Collection`, you can't access `manager_id` without looping, but you actually don't have to in this case. If you want to query `id` for those that match any `manager_id`, you can do that via a `whereIn()` clause, combined with the `pluck()` method:

```
$query->whereIn('id', $expiringUsers->pluck('manager_id'));
```

And, your code can be simplified to:

```
public function scopeManagers(){ 
  return $this->where(function($query){
    $query->whereIn('id', $this->ExpiringContractors()->pluck('manager_id'));
  })->get();
}
```

Note: `ExpiringContractors` should really be `expiringContractors`; function names are generally `camelCase`.

Comment: I knew I was on the right track... this makes perfect sense and works great, thanks. Yep, thanks for pointing out my function name error, I'll get it corrected... also needs () at the end of it in your answer.

Comment: No problem! And it doesn't actually; if you omit the `()`, it'll automatically convert it to a `Collection`/`Model` instance (depends on the relationship type). In your case, either will work (since it's using `$this` directly), but yeah, `()` is only ever required if you explicitly need a `Builder` instance.

Comment: Er, I might be missing something; is `ExpiringContractors()` a relationship? Or a method that explicitly returns a `Collection`? You're right; might need `()` in your case depending on what it is.

Comment: Yes expiringContractors() returns a collection.

Comment: Gotcha; misunderstanding on my part then. If it was a relationship function, like `public function expiringContractors(){ return $this->hasMany(...); })` then you can omit the `()`, but if it's something else, then yes, you do need them. Updated answer :)

Comment: Nice explanation :)